# How do I vary pen intensity more with my Wacom pen in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, line-art

I have a Wacom Intuos with a Wacom pro pen with 4096 levels of sensitivity. I've always had trouble making my lines' intensity vary. What am I missing here? I know there's supposed to be a graph where I can adjust this in the Wacom Desktop center, but I can't find it. Is my Wacom tablet just incapable of supporting that much line intensity? (I'd imagine the settings were in Photoshop, not tied to my pen or the tablet, so I've been very confused.)

I want my lines to look like the ones in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBE-RTFkXDk) at 2:04. Here's how my lines look: [image]

Thanks.

Comment: I cant say for certain, but your image looks like it has **both** size **and** opacity set to pressure. You may want to merely turn of opacity (transfer) in the Brush Dynamics within Photoshop. -- I didn't sit through the 11 minute video to try and figure out what you are referring to there.

Comment: Something is definitely off. I've worked with this video before and my intuos is older and my lines are thicker. Have you set the pressure in your device configuration? It might be the brush used is too small. Hard to say without seeing your configuration.

Comment: I just wanted to add that if anyone with a similar issue sees this question, from what I can see it's all about the right brush settings and nothing more. — Driver issues aside OP could've had both a Wacom drawing tablet and Photoshop from like 20 years ago and they would've been able to do this just fine. — To me it seems like OP just needed to make the brush bigger and that's about it. The other issue is that in his brush, opacity is controlled by the pen pressure too. Didn't watch this with audio, but it seems to explain opacity and size pressure settings: https://youtu.be/9rtspMw1-OA?t=275

Comment: Also [brush settings](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-modifying-brushes.html#brush_panel_overview) give you more control over how that stuff works. Not much in this case perhaps, but it does allow you to set a minimum diameter. Normally it just goes from 0 to whatever the current brush size is, which is why I said that OP's problem with "not enough variety in size" was brush size.

Answer (score 0):

Using pen is about experience too, and smoother lines will come with practice, even when you try to vary pressure intensity within your lines.

In the video, like Scott said, there is no opacity variation, you can un-check the transfer option. You can also try to put the spacing to 0 in the "Brush tip shape" options.
Finally having a bigger brush in size let photoshop have more room to influence the levels of intensity.

(sorry if my english is kinda hard to read, not my native language)